# Which settings are responsible for literal mouseover styling in PHP?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, color-scheme

I use PhpStorm, and when I mouse-over on any primitive literal (string, int, ...), it opens a popup displaying the value while the code itself is highlighted (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

With my (heavily modified) color scheme, this highlight makes the code (especially strings) hard to read. I tried to change various color scheme settings but none had an effect on it, and I can't think of what setting to look for.

Which settings are responsible for this behavior? And which color scheme setting determines the highlight style?

Comment: have you look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#share-color-scheme) ? or [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001775480-How-can-I-change-highlight-color-)?

Comment: I'm not sure what I changed, but the behavior is suddenly gone completely.

"Jump to Colors and Fonts" is very useful though; thanks for the pointer!

Comment: The behaviour is back (I guess it was only temporarily glitched out or something). Jump to Colors and Fonts doesn't show anything helpful for it, as the styling is based on cursor position, not caret position, I guess.

Comment: @Sinthorion Try recoding some short screencast/gif that will show the issue: seeing the actual action may help identifying what is happening. Obviously, you would need to share your color scheme as well. Other than that I may only suggest to base your color scheme on some exiting dark scheme (e.g. Darcula) and not a light one -- it should work better this way (in case if you do not overwrite some styles..)